# Custom claims vs accessing refs in security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

We're integrating our Firebase app with Twitter auth and use the Twitter `screen_name` as our main human-readable username everywhere in the db.

When it comes to security rules, this is obviously a drawback: We don't know the `screen_name` as it is not included in `auth.token`. What we can do, is `root.child('users').child($screen_name).child('uid').val() === auth.uid`.

Only way to get the Twitter `screen_name` into the `auth.token` security rule context is via custom claims, right? What's the preferred method of doing this? Other pattern suggestions for human readable usernames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option to [add custom claims to user tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) is a relatively new addition to Firebase Authentication. Before this feature was available, storing additional information in the database was the only way to accomplish many scenarios. For that reason you'll find that most samples, questions, and documentation shows how to store the additional information in the database.

Storing additional claims in the token has many advantages though. A few of those:

- Custom claims are already available in your security rules, while reading information from the database often requires an additional read.
- Custom claims are available in the security rules for all products, while reading additional information from the database only works in database rules.

There are also a few advantages to using the database to store additional information:

- The information in the database can be relatively unlimited, while the custom claims information must be kept really short.
- I often prefer seeing the additional information in the database, because it's easier to scan the info that way.

If you're using the Twitter screen name in your security rules, it sounds like a natural fit for custom claims. If you also want to show the Twitter screen name for users in the UI, you'll probably *also* want to store it in the database.

Comment: Neat! I read up on custom claims and we'll go with that option: We already have a function in place for `auth.onCreate` & just add the `screen_name` there. Should be available instantly on first login, right? And of course we're also keeping track of the `screen_name` to make the db itself more readable. It's more of a concession to our devs. Thanks, Frank!

Comment: Also, you said: Custom claims are available in the security rules for all products. You mean across Firebase products, e.g. Firestore?

Comment: Yup. The claims are available in the security rules for the Realtime Database, Cloud Storage for Firebase, and Cloud Firestore.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Where I can find an example of how to add custom claims?

Comment: Good question. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims. I also added the link in my answer.