# Read and write permission rule for admin user and auth user Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm trying to create an admin user who will have the permission to read and write in the database of all Firebase user data.

This is my database structure:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "uid1" : {
      "name" : "Josh",
      "permission": "user"
    },
    "uid2" : {
      "name" : "June",
      "permission": "admin"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my current permission rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this rules, all users have the permission to read or write their own data. But how can I define a rule to make the `"permission": "admin"` user have that read and write permission too?

Comment: Check out how I did it in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39063833/4916627). And note that having the permissions in the user data itself is a bad idea because a user has access to their own data meaning they can change their own permissions.

Comment: Instead of adding the permissions in the database, I'd nowadays recommend that you use custom claims for these. See the [Firebase documentation on custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims), [my answer here on the difference between the two approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653995/custom-claims-vs-accessing-refs-in-security-rules0 and these [previous questions about the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+database+custom+claim).